# Не могу записать в базу данных больше 2-ух элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, база-данных, sqlite3

Не могу записать в базу данных больше `2-ух` элементов:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/RAINGM/desktop/testdatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

battletag = input('Введите данные: ')

for i in cursor.execute(f"SELECT tag FROM tagtest1"):
    battletags1 = i[0]

battletags = [battletags1]
battletags.append(battletag)

if battletags1 == 'none':
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE tagtest1 SET tag = '{battletag}'")
    conn.commit()

else:
    cursor.execute(f'UPDATE tagtest1 SET tag = "{battletags}"')
    conn.commit()
```

*Ошибка:*

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:/Users/RAINGM/Desktop/Untitled-1.py", line 53, in <module>
>     cursor.execute(f'UPDATE tagtest1 SET tag = "{battletags}"')
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "['asd', 'asd']": syntax error
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/RAINGM/desktop/testdatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

battletag = input('Введите данные: ')

for i in cursor.execute(f"SELECT tag FROM tagtest1"):
    battletags1 = i[0]

battletags = [battletags1]
battletags.append(battletag)

if battletags1 == 'none':
    battletags_str = str(battletags).replace('\'', '')
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE tagtest1 SET tag = '{battletags_str}'")
    conn.commit()

else:
    battletags_str = str(battletags).replace('\'', '')
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE tagtest1 SET tag = '{battletags_str}'")
    conn.commit()
```